# HttpWebRequest add cookie exception

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to create `HttpWebRequest` with a cookie:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myweb.com/get_my_web/");
        req.Method = "POST";

        if (req.CookieContainer == null)
        {
            req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        System.Net.Cookie newCookie = new System.Net.Cookie("sessionid", AppData.sessionid,
                        "\\", "myweb.com");
        req.CookieContainer.Add(newCookie);
```

In `req.CookieContainer.Add(newCookie);` i'm getting this Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.CookieException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The 'Domain'='myweb.com' part of the cookie is invalid.
```

Any idea what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading - problem is in cookie path and not domain. `"\\"` is invalid path, I think you meant `/`:

```
System.Net.Cookie newCookie = new System.Net.Cookie("sessionid", AppData.sessionid,
    "/", "myweb.com");
```